# when i trying to add a data to database with Django i got error calls NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_login.password

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

The strange thing is I cant send data and add it to data base when I make **user_data.save()** comment and open the page then delete the # but when I go our from the page and try to join it again I got the error " **NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_login.password** "

models.py folder

```
from django.db import models

class Login(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

views.py folder

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Login

def index(request):
    index_context = {
        'name': 'yahia',
        'age': '20',
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', index_context)

def about(request):

    usernamee = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user_data = Login(username=usernamee, password=password)
    user_data.save()

    return render(request, 'pages/about.html')
```

here the **user_data.save()** when i comment it like this #user_data.save() the code word and the page opens and i can send the data when i remove the # but when i restart the page i get the error

admin.py page

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Login
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Login)
```

the full error

```
IntegrityError at /about/
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_login.password
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_login.password
Exception Location: C:\Users\a\OneDrive - Higher Technological Institute\Desktop\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\a\OneDrive - Higher Technological Institute\Desktop\test\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\a\\OneDrive - Higher Technological '
 'Institute\\Desktop\\test\\project',
 'c:\\users\\a\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\a\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\a\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\a\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'C:\\Users\\a\\OneDrive - Higher Technological Institute\\Desktop\\test',
 'C:\\Users\\a\\OneDrive - Higher Technological '
 'Institute\\Desktop\\test\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 19 Sep 2021 02:10:55 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have first check some steps that I have mentioned here.

1. Check you have registered your model correctly.
2. Check through which method you have submitted your form. If your method is POST then write a proper code in views.py to listen that request.

   ```
    def index(request):
         return HttpResponse("This is home page.")
    def about(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
             username=request.POST.get('username')
             password=request.POST.get('password')
             user_data=Login(username=username,password=password)
             user_data.save()
             return redirect('index')

         return render(request,'about.html')
   ```
3. Check you have `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

   ```
     python manage.py makemigrations
     python manage.py migrate
   ```

4.Check what method you have used in form, and write proper code to listen that request.

```
 <form action="about" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username : </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> <br>
        <label for="password">Password : </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

5. Check you have register your app correctly in `settings.py`.

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
      ]
   ```
6. If your `method` is `GET` then write code to listen that request.

I have mentioned all the possible error that I have done and I got the same error that you have. So, finally check your code and run again.

If there is any spelling mistake in my code then please didn't mind. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much i did it step by step and it worked, i guess my error was because i did not write a proper code in views.py to listen that request

Comment: May be. Keep it up........